# How to make image buttons stay in place when re sizing web browser

Tags: css

This is my image-button for my website. http://puu.sh/cK7Sf/6309c39cdb.jpg When I re-size my browser it goes over here http://puu.sh/cK7VU/f17dafcc41.jpg

Here is my code

**HTML**

```
<div class="Nav">
<div id="buttons">
    <a href="/"><div id="home_button"></div></a>
```

**CSS**

```
#home_button {
background-image: url("home.png");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
width: 150px;
height: 60px;
position: absolute;
top: 196px;
left: 502px;
z-index: 10;
}
```

I am new to web developing so please don't hate :)

Comment: What are you trying to do? The problem is the element is positioned absolute. So as the parent container shrinks, the button is a static left 502px. Also, <a> is an inline element, and <div> is block. Not sure why the first screenshot shows it on the left, need to see the parent container css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created an example to show you what a basic `nav` bar styling looks like.

### Demo on [dabblet](http://dabblet.com/gist/ede766e097f37027af22)

#### HTML:

```
<body>
<!--Navigation-Bar-Container-->
<div class="nav-container">
    <!--Navigation-Bar-Item-Wrapper-->
    <div class="nav">
        <!--Items-->
        <div id="menu-item-1" class="menu-item">Item 1</div>
        <div id="menu-item-2" class="menu-item">Item 2</div>
        <div id="menu-item-3" class="menu-item">Item 3</div>
        <div id="menu-item-4" class="menu-item">Item 4</div>
        <div id="menu-item-5" class="menu-item">Item 5</div>
        <hr />
    </div>
</div>
<!--Content-->
</body>
```

#### CSS:

```
body {
    background: url(http://s25.postimg.org/b6q25p4p7/black_thread.png) repeat black;
}
hr {
    color: #777777;
}
.nav-container {
    top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
.nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    maring: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.menu-item {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    color: #777777;
}
.menu-item:hover {
    background-color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
```

Comment: When i click on them i want them to go to another page, which i cannot do with these buttons. Please help

Comment: @Test54545 - Could you copy your entire code to [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and give me the link?

Comment: [Here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/j3y0azzp/3/)! I've wrapped those `div`s around `a` tags. Change `http://www.google.com/` to the location of the page you want. Additionally I've added `@keyframes` animation for when you hover over the nemu items. If you want to change the animation time, you will have to change `0.8s` in `.menu-item:hover` to the time you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do, some adjustment needed, not sure why the button is absolutely positioned, or what the background image is for, but here goes:

HTML:

```
   <ul class='menu'>
    <li><a href="/">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Link 2</a></li>
    </ul>
```

CSS:

```
.menu {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 0.2em solid black;
    border-radius: 10%;
    padding: .5em;
    background: linear-gradient(lightblue, blue);
}
.menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
```